# Undetermined coefficients and zero roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I have a differential equation $L(y(t))=g(t)$ where $L$ is a linear differential operator and $g(t)$ is a polynomial, I suppose as particular solution a polynomial of the SAME degree. I find that reasonable only in all the examples I see where $y$ is included in the operator (for example $y''-2y'+y=3t$). In those cases (and only in those), when I substitute the suposed solution $y_p=A_mx^m+...+A_0$ with undetermined coefficients, the term with higher exponent has not vanished. If $y$ is not included ($y''+y'=g(t)$) I don't have that.

For a moment I thought I understood, because in the case of second order, whenever I do not have $y$ included i will have a zero root in the polynomial, but that is not sufficient to multiply the $y_p$ by t, because as a whole, $y_p$, even though it contains a constant, is not linearly dependent of the homogeneous constant solution. Also, when I put an equation like $y''-2y'=e^{2t}$ in Wolfram, it multiplies it by $t$ as well, "to account for $e^{2t}$ in the complimentary solution". Apparently I also do not get when I multiply by $t$.

Thanks.

Comment: @Moo, in that page it's clear what I am saying. All examples have y as a term. None of them is lacking y.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = A_mt^m+\dots+A_0$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, then $y' = A_mmt^{m-1}+\dots+A_1$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1$ and $y'' = A_mm(m-1)t^{m-2}+\dots+2A_2$ is a polynomial of degree $m-2$.

If you take some linear combination of them (with constant coefficients), then obviously the degree of that combination is going to be the highest degree of the polynomials included in that sum. If $y$ is part of the sum, then the degree will be $m$. If $y$ is not included, but $y'$, then the degree will be $m-1$. If neither $y$ nor $y'$ is present, but $y''$ is, then the degree is $m-2$.

So when you see $y''-2y' + y = 3t$, the lh side will have degree $m$, and the rh side as degree $1$, so obviously you want $m =1$. If you have $y'' + y' = 3t^2-7t$, now the degree on the lh side will be $m-1$ and on the right is $2$, so you need $m-1 = 2$, thus $m=3$. If you have $y''' - y'' = 3t-3$, then the degree on the left is $m-2$, and on the right is $1$, so you need $m - 2 = 1$, and thus $m = 3$. The reason you were having trouble is that instead of reasoning through what degree will be needed, you were demanding a single approach. Sorry, but one size does not fit all.

But when $y$ is not found, there is another approach: If everything you are seeing is a derivative, then you should solve for the derivative first, and just integrate to the get the function. For example, you ask about $y'' - 2y' = e^{2t}$. Let $u = y'$, then $y'' = u'$, so this equation becomes $$u' -2u = e^{2t}$$ Since we know how exponentials behave under differentiation, the obvious thing to try here is $u = Ae^{2t}$. Then $u' = 2Ae^{2t}$ and $$u' -2u = 2Ae^{2t} -2Ae^{2t} = 0$$ Which doesn't work.

So why did Wolfram Alpha multiply by $t$? Because the easy idea doesn't work, so we have to try something different. What next? Well, if a constant $A$ doesn't work, replace it with a function of $t$: $u = p(t)e^{2t}$, so $u' = p'e^{2t} +2pe^{2t}$ and the equation becomes
$$(p'e^{2t} +2pe^{2t}) - 2(pe^{2t}) = e^{2t}$$
Dividing out the exponentinal leaves $p' = 1$, which has the general solution $p(t) = t + A$. This gives $u = pe^{2t} = te^{2t} + Ae^{2t}$. And integrating $u$ to get $y$ gives
$$y=\frac{2t-1}4e^{2t} + \frac A2e^{2t} + C\\y = \frac t2e^{2t} + Be^{2t} + C$$
where $B = \frac {2A - 1}4$. But since $A$ was an arbitrary constant, we can adjust it to get any $B$ we want. That is, $B$ is is just a different arbitrary constant.

The is no magic rule "here you multiply by $t$, and there you don't". What you do is *explore* things until you find what works.